# Could Turkish "küçük" and Mongolian "жижиг" be related?

Tags: etymology, turkish, turkic-languages, mongolian, altaic-hypothesis

I'm in Mongolia trying to learn some Mongolian and I've come across their cute word for "litlle", "small": **жижиг**.

On previous trips through Turkey I recall learning a similar cute word for "little", "small": **küçük**.

I'm no fanboi of the Altaic Hypothesis but it's pretty accepted here and of course there is lots of contact between Mongolic and Turkic to allow loanwords by some route. Though I would've thought this would be core vocabulary not usually borrowed.

Answer (score 7):

The first two similar syllables of the Mongolian word pose a difficult problem for those who want to correlate them with the two different syllables of the Turkic word. Actually, the modern Khalkha Mongolian `жижиг` comes from the Old Mongolian `didig`, which also has the two first syllables identical, and the Turkish `küçük` comes from the Proto-Turkic `*kičük`. So, my answer is: no, they are not related.

Comment: It's also reminiscent of Turkish *çocuk* "child".